# Require a child of an abstract class in method arguments

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

I have a method that takes SubForm object and displays it.

```
public void subFormLauncher(object sender, SubForm f)
{
    if (f == null)
    {
        f = new SubForm(this);    // This line is problematic
        f.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        if (!f.Visible)
        {
            f.Show();
        }
        f.Activate();
    }
}
```

VS gets angry because SubForm is an abstract class and I was accidentally instantiating an instance of it (fair).

```
public abstract class SubForm : Form
{
    public SubForm(frmMain f) { }
    public abstract void InitForm();
}
```

Is there a way to specify in the arguments of subFormLauncher that I want a child of SubForm? Something like:

```
public void subFormLauncher(object sender, <T> extends SubForm f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something with your whole appraoch seems "off":

`public void subFormLauncher(object sender, SubForm f)` reminds me of a Event (object sender) but that does not look anything like a Event should.

It is also rather wierd that you are passing a Form as a parameter, much less the work you are doing on it. You are putting it into the foregroind if you give it, but if not you instantiate it?

There is a rather high chance that you are deep in a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

You will not get around specifying the exact type you want created. One approach might be adding some generic into the mix:

```
public void subFormLauncher<T>(object sender, T f) where T : SubForm 
{
    if (f == null)
    {
        f = new T(this);    // This line is problematic
        f.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        if (!f.Visible)
        {
            f.Show();
        }
        f.Activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `new()` constraint on the type. Also, you're not using the default constructor. So this plainly won't compile.

Comment: @gnud is right. Replacing the constructor with `f = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { this });` will fix that. But the point you made about the Event handler was right. I wanted to provide a default method to show any given form.

Comment: I do not quite get what you try to tell me. `public SubForm(frmMain f) ` is a valid constructor. If a constructor is not likely to work (as each child might or might not have one), a FactoryMethod might be the way to go.

Comment: Or just `new T(); T.Parent = this;`. Why complicate?

Comment: @gnud: That asumes Parent is a public field/not a readonly property. The Constructor input is often used for values that should not be publically setable/setable more then once. Of course if that is true, then assignment is the simpelst way.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void subFormLauncher(object sender, SubForm f)
```

Is already declaring that the object passed in must be of type "SubForm", the problem is your logic is trying to new a subform up here:

```
f = new SubForm(this);    // This line is problematic
```

But as its abstract, you can't new one up. If you remove this, and don't allow subform to be null when passed into your method, problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

You could use an interface and request this in your method call.

Comment: How would this help?

Comment: I can't use an interface because I need to inherit from Form, which is a class

Comment: I see. I was thinking of adding an interface to the abstract class. But then again this is not needed as shown by gmn. gmn's answer should be fine...